# Align rows of a matrix to the left/right by first non-NaN element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix where some rows' leading elements are NaNs (the number of leading NaNs may differ for each row). After the first non-NaN element, other elements in a row are guaranteed to be non-NaN as well.

Example:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[np.nan,np.nan,1],[np.nan,1,2]])
```

I want to shift each row so that they align to the left by the first non-NaN element, like so:

```
B = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,np.nan,np.nan],[1,2,np.nan]])
```

Then I want to perform some operations (dependent on the relative index in the row), e.g.:

```
C = B*2
```

and then shift the rows back to align to the right once again:

```
D = np.array([[2,4,6],[np.nan,np.nan,2],[np.nan,2,4]])
```

I can think of a naive loopy solution that gets positions of the first non-NaN elements in each row and then performs shifts rowwise accordingly, but I suppose a more elegant (and probably much simpler) solution exists. I am willing to use either pandas or numpy to represent the data and their native methods/any 3rd party utilities to manipulate it. Execution time is also of no major concern.

Comment: is the operation you want to perform dependent on the relative index in the row? because otherwise you can just use e.g. `D = A*2` and get the D you want.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 yes, it is dependent, will edit to reflect that.